# Custom listview contains imagebutton,play sound when button is click

Tags: java, android

I have custom Lisview containing textview and imagebutton...i want to play specific audio file for every button in a row.the audio files are in raw folder,how can i do this?

```
MainActivity.java
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ListViewAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<DictionaryApp> arrayList = new ArrayList();
String[] cuyuno;
String[] edefinition;
EditText editsearch;
String[] english;
ListView list;
int[] sound;
String[] tagalog;
String[] tbaybay;
String[] tdefinition;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    this.tagalog = new String[]{"alaala", "araw", "baliw", "basura", "kahirapan", "kaibigan", "kakatuwa", "kasunduan", "daluyang-luha", "dambuhala", "dulo", "dukutin", "gawin", "guni-guni", "hagdan", "hintay", "idlip", "idolo", "maganda", "masama", "masarap", "matalino", "nagtanan", "nawala", "pagbibitiw", "paikliin"};
    this.tbaybay = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tbaybay);
    this.tdefinition = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tdefinition);
    this.cuyuno = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cuyuno);
    this.english = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.eword);
    this.edefinition = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.edefinition);
    this.sound = new int[]{R.raw.alaala, R.raw.araw, R.raw.baliw, R.raw.basura, R.raw.kaibigan, R.raw.kakatuwa, R.raw.kasunduan};
    this.list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    for (int i = 0; i < this.tagalog.length; i++) {
        this.arrayList.add(new DictionaryApp(this.tagalog[i], this.tbaybay[i], this.tdefinition[i], this.cuyuno[i], this.english[i], this.edefinition[i]));
    }
    this.adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, this.arrayList);
    this.list.setAdapter(this.adapter);
    this.editsearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);
    this.editsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            MainActivity.this.adapter.filter(MainActivity.this.editsearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()));
        }
    });
}
}



ListViewAdapter.java
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private ArrayList<DictionaryApp> arraylist;
private List<DictionaryApp> dictionaryapplist = null;
LayoutInflater inflater;
Context mContext;

public class ViewHolder {
    TextView cuyuno;
    TextView edefinition;
    TextView english;
    ImageButton sound;
    TextView tagalog;
    TextView tbaybay;
    TextView tdefinition;
}

public ListViewAdapter(Context context, List<DictionaryApp> dictionaryapplist) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.dictionaryapplist = dictionaryapplist;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.mContext);
    this.arraylist = new ArrayList();
    this.arraylist.addAll(dictionaryapplist);
}

public int getCount() {
    return this.dictionaryapplist.size();
}

public DictionaryApp getItem(int position) {
    return (DictionaryApp) this.dictionaryapplist.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return (long) position;
}

public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);
        holder.tagalog = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tagalog);
        holder.tbaybay = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tbaybay);
        holder.tdefinition = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tdefinition);
        holder.cuyuno = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cuyuno);
        holder.english = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.english);
        holder.edefinition = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.edefinition);
        holder.sound = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.sound);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    holder.tagalog.setText(((DictionaryApp) this.dictionaryapplist.get(position)).getTagalog());
    holder.tbaybay.setText(((DictionaryApp) this.dictionaryapplist.get(position)).getTbaybay());
    holder.tdefinition.setText(((DictionaryApp) this.dictionaryapplist.get(position)).getTdefinition());
    holder.cuyuno.setText(((DictionaryApp) this.dictionaryapplist.get(position)).getCuyuno());
    holder.english.setText(((DictionaryApp) this.dictionaryapplist.get(position)).getEnglish());
    holder.edefinition.setText(((DictionaryApp) this.dictionaryapplist.get(position)).getEdefinition());

    view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ListViewAdapter.this.mContext, SingleItemView.class);
            intent.putExtra("tagalog", ((DictionaryApp) ListViewAdapter.this.dictionaryapplist.get(position)).getTagalog());
            intent.putExtra("tbaybay", ((DictionaryApp) ListViewAdapter.this.dictionaryapplist.get(position)).getTbaybay());
            intent.putExtra("tdefinition", ((DictionaryApp) ListViewAdapter.this.dictionaryapplist.get(position)).getTdefinition());
            intent.putExtra("cuyuno", ((DictionaryApp) ListViewAdapter.this.dictionaryapplist.get(position)).getCuyuno());
            intent.putExtra("english", ((DictionaryApp) ListViewAdapter.this.dictionaryapplist.get(position)).getEnglish());
            intent.putExtra("edefinition", ((DictionaryApp) ListViewAdapter.this.dictionaryapplist.get(position)).getEdefinition());
            ListViewAdapter.this.mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return view;
}

public void filter(String charText) {
    charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    this.dictionaryapplist.clear();
    if (charText.length() == 0) {
        this.dictionaryapplist.addAll(this.arraylist);
    } else {
        Iterator i$ = this.arraylist.iterator();
        while (i$.hasNext()) {
            DictionaryApp da = (DictionaryApp) i$.next();
            if (da.getTagalog().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) {
                this.dictionaryapplist.add(da);
            }
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}


DictionaryApp.java
public class DictionaryApp {
private String cuyuno;
private String edefinition;
private String english;
private String tagalog;
private String tbaybay;
private String tdefinition;

public DictionaryApp(String tagalog, String tbaybay, String tdefinition, String cuyuno, String english, String edefinition) {
    this.tagalog = tagalog;
    this.tbaybay = tbaybay;
    this.tdefinition = tdefinition;
    this.cuyuno = cuyuno;
    this.english = english;
    this.edefinition = edefinition;
}

public String getTagalog() {
    return this.tagalog;
}

public String getTbaybay() {
    return this.tbaybay;
}

public String getTdefinition() {
    return this.tdefinition;
}

public String getCuyuno() {
    return this.cuyuno;
}

public String getEnglish() {
    return this.english;
}

public String getEdefinition() {
    return this.edefinition;
}   

}
```

The audio files are in raw folder,what i want to come out is that the audio will play in the imagebutton inside the listview....i am newbie in android, help is what i appreciate the most...thanks

Comment: What's error/issue you find with the above code? Post your direct issue instead the whole main problem.

Comment: I think you should read answer here [how-can-i-use-music-in-raw-folder-in-this-music-player](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23227939/3832212)

Comment: You suggestion might help,but i dont know where to put,should it be in main activity class or in ListViewAdapter Class?

Answer (score 0):

To play media files, you can do it like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16797922/1750013

To play different audio for each of the row, you can use switch case to select different files based upon row number. Polymorphism is another option. Otherwise you have to be more specific about the application logic, then only someone will be able to suggest another logic. Hope it helps :)